# what actually does ths error mean when i try to run my code i ran into the erro, the error in metioned beneath the code

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, pycharm, video-processing

This is the code I am facing the problem with I have written few functions in my library named rohith(link provided at the end of the code please feel free to download it)

```
        import cv2
        import rohith
        import numpy as np
        videoPath = 'project_video.mp4'
        cap = cv2.VideoCapture(videoPath)

        def lane_tracking(img, lines):
            copy_image= np.copy(img)
            merginig_img = np.zeros((img.shape[0],img.shape[1],3),
                                  dtype = np.uint8)
            for line in lines:
                for x1,y1,x2,y2 in line:
                    cv2.line(merginig_img,(x1,y1),(x2,y2),(10,255,255),
                             thickness=4)

            merged_img =cv2.addWeighted(copy_image,
                                        0.8,
                                        merginig_img,
                                        1,
                                        0.0)
          ''merging the lane detected image(which includes only roi) with original image(frame)''
            return  merged_img

        while(True):


             ret,frame = cap.read()

             processed_image = rohith.preprocess(frame)

             width = processed_image.shape[0]
             height = processed_image.shape[1]

             region_of_interest_vertices = [
                  (0, width), (height / 2, width / 2), (height, width)
             ]

             gray_scale = cv2.cvtColor(processed_image,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
             edge_detection = cv2.Canny(gray_scale, 55, 150)               
             cropped_image=rohith.region_of_interest(edge_detection,
                                      np.array([region_of_interest_vertices],
                                      np.int32))



             lane_tracking1 = cv2.HoughLinesP(cropped_image,
                                             rho=6, theta=np.pi / 60,
                                             threshold=160,
                                             lines=np.array([]),
                                             minLineLength=40,
                                             maxLineGap=25)

             line_added_img = lane_tracking(processed_image,lane_tracking1)



             cv2.imshow('edge detected image with only lanes',cropped_image)
             cv2.imshow('video_with_lane_lines', line_added_img)



             if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('p'):
                 break
        cap.release()
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

1. ///following the error I am facing with the code when I try to run I am using pycharm  to run my code in python (link to rohith library------->>>>              https://drive.google.com/file/d/1TKXwGcBZXKS5Y3n9aXze5TVVjaOc9kB6/view?usp=sharing)

   ```
           Traceback (most recent call last):
           File 
          "C:/Users/dell/PycharmProjects/lane_detection/test02.py",line28,
           in <module>
           processed_image = rohith.preprocess(frame)
           File "C:\Users\dell\PycharmProjects\lane_detection\rohith.py", 
           line 5, in
           preprocess
           filtering = cv2.GaussianBlur(frame, (5,5),0)
           cv2.error: OpenCV(4.1.2) C:\projects\opencv- 
           python\opencv\modules\core\src\matrix.cpp:757:
           error: (-215:Assertion failed) dims <= 2 && step[0] > 0 in 
           function
           'cv::Mat::locateROI'
           Process finished with exit code 1
   ```

Comment: Please format this correctly. It's very hard to read without formatting.

Comment: sorry for the discomfort.. hope this is good now (formated)

Comment: You added a code block, yes. But now your code is overly indented, has random double quotes, and your traceback is not actually properly formatted. Please revisit this one more time, this time carefully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is that the function was supplied with a smaller image than expected. Resizing the image resolved the issue.